# what is difference between MaterializedPostgreSQL Engine and PostgreSQL Engine in Clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

why we need this? since the docs say:

> MaterializedPostgreSQL
> Creates a ClickHouse database with tables from PostgreSQL database.

> PostgreSQL
> Allows to connect to databases on a remote PostgreSQL server.

I cannot see clearly the difference between them?

when to use each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MaterializedPostgreSQL` will use replication slots and will physically replicate data from PostgreSQL to ClickHouse

`PostgreSQL` it's just a proxy table engine.
When you try `SELECT FROM postgreqsql_table_engine` then your clickhouse query will rewrite. GROUP BY, ORDER BY and HAVING BY sections will remove and query just proxy to remote PostgreSQL server, after it GROUP BY ORDER BY and HAVING BY clause will apply on clickhouse side.

Comment: It boils down to where the final data resides.  Materialized copies to ClickHouse, the table engine leaves the data on PostgreSQL.  If you want ClickHouse performance on the data and are willing to pay the cost of replication, you want Materialized.  If there is a small amount of data that you just want to join with ClickHouse data you can leave it on Postgres and use the table engine.

Comment: Also note that the MaterializedPostgres engine is experimental, the table engine is not.

Comment: that nice, I have second question, how about the performance? is that  MaterializedPostgreSQL faster PostgreSQL Engine? MaterializedPostgreSQL as fast as Clickhouse since data is on Clickhouse and PostgreSQL is slower than Clickhouse?

Comment: Yes, you right, MaterializedPostgreSQL much faster than PostgreSQL but require disk space on clickhouse server

Answer (score 0):

Essentially , materializedPostgresSQL is having a copy of all your postgres data in Clickhouse .

It solves two problems ,

1. You can't really create Materialized views on a postgres table engine since the data is not available in clickhouse , in the sense that a PostgreSql table engine is essentially running clickhouse queries in PSQL
2. Makes it easy to recreate all your schemas without having to write all your DDLs